# Distributive/CCC categories, exponentials

Tags: ct.category-theory

Are there standard approaches to show that a non CCC category is distributive?

By the way, I know that a CCC category is distributive and I suppose that what makes the things work is that there is an exponential. But I have tried (not too hard) to prove the existence of the $(A\oplus B)\times C \rightarrow (A\times C) \oplus (B\times C)$ in a CCC category using exponentials, but I didn't succeed....any idea or pointer to an article ?

Thanks

Comment: In a CCC, $(-) \times C$ is a left adjoint and thus preserves colimits (including coproducts).

Comment: @Varkor Thanks varkor but can you elaborate a little bit, I'm just trying to learn CT by myself and your answer is a bit short for my level of knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @Gianfranco Left adjoint functors preserve colimits, and right adjoint functors preserve limits.  Coproducts are a special kind of colimit, so left adjoints will preserve coproducts since they preserve colimits. In a CCC, the functor $(-)\times C$ that sends an object $X$ to $X\times C$ and an arrow $f:X\to Y$ to $f\times1_C$ is a left adjoint, so in particular it preserves colimits meaning that the image of a colimit will be the colimit of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explicit execution of "left adjoints preserve colimits":

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Hom}((A + B) \times C, D)
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(A + B, D^C) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(A, D^C) \times \mathrm{Hom}(B, D^C) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(A \times C, D) \times \mathrm{Hom}(B \times C, D) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}((A \times C) + (B \times C), D)
\end{align*}

Therefore, by the (covariant) Yoneda lemma, $(A + B) \times C$ is isomorphic to $(A \times C) + (B \times C)$.

Answer (score 0):

The distributivity condition is equivalent to asking that the functor $(-) \times C$ preserves coproducts for all $C \in \mathscr C$. This is easy to verify abstractly for any cartesian-closed category since $(-) \times C \dashv (-)^C$ and left adjoints preserve coproducts (indeed, [any colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoints+preserve+%28co-%29limits)), as Andrej Bauer proves in their answer.

Assuming you have a concrete characterisation of the products and coproducts in your category $\mathscr C$, you may simply unwind the definitions on both sides of the equation and check the two objects are isomorphic. This is because it suffices to show that [any natural isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3946036) exists between $(A + B) \times C$ and $A \times C + B \times C$ to imply distributivity.

For simpler heuristics, you can check that $\mathscr C$ satisfies the [properties of any distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category), e.g. the initial object must be strict.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your answers, gives me enough tools to go forward. Thanks again.